# Bootstrap 3 Absolute Row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new with Bootstrap 3 . I tried to make relative row's and 3 absolute row's, but when I made them I found that I have to add every screen class? Why? Anyway it works in md and sm screen, but not working with phone size -xs-

**HTML :**

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 RelativeRow " >
        <img src="img/Plans/1.jpg"  class="img-responsive"   />
         <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-xm-12 AbsoluteRoW NoPadding TripInfo " ></div>
        </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

Live example [Here](http://mohammadsamy.com/Goejaza/index.html)

*The relative box is the London View .

Comment: First of all, don't mess with the default grid layout unless you sh*t to break in all sorts of unexpected way. Second, I'm still not sure what you are trying to do here

Comment: You use `xm` instead of `xs`

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 3 is a mobile first framework.  If you use an col-xs class it will apply to all screen sizes xs and larger.  You only use other screen size classes when you want it to display differently on a particular screen.